# Uncaught TypeError: Object function(arg1 , arg2) has no method 'apply'

Tags: jquery, click, clone

I wanted to copy one click event from one element to another i am doing in following mannner 
which is not working

```
 var arr = $("#engagement_box_content_generic_mention>.data_box>.load_mentions_data_box");
     $.each ( arr , function( key , value){

            console.log( $(this).attr("onclick") );
            if ( key == 0 ) {
                $("#abc").click( $(this).attr('onclick') );
            }
});
```

console.log gives me like this 
print_1317(1317, 201205, 24, 11, 'no');

but when i click on applyed element abc  it gives error

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Object print_1317(1317, 201205, 24, 11, 'no'); has no method 'apply'
```

thanks in advance