# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply'

Tags: ajax, jquery

jQuery is throwing the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'apply'
>
> f.event.dispatch
>
> h.handle.i

I've found these related posts, but couldn't solve the problem using them:
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032659/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-object-has-no-method-apply), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032659/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-object-has-no-method-apply) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741588/uncaught-typeerror-object-functionarg1-arg2-has-no-method-apply).

Here's the troublesome code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('form.rating').click({
    cancelShow:true,
    callback: function(ui, type, new_value) {
        var values = ui.$form.serializeArray();
        values.push({
            'name': 'rating',
            'value': new_value
        });
        values = jQuery.param(values);
        var msg = ui.$form.attr('update-msg');
        $(msg).removeClass('hidden');
        $(msg).show();
        $(msg).find('div.msg-default').show();
        $(msg).find('div.msg-result').hide();
        $.ajax({
            'type': 'POST',
            'dataType': 'json',
            'url': ui.$form.attr('action'),
            'data': values
        }).done(function(data) { 
            var overall_rating = ui.$form.attr('update-overall');
            if(overall_rating && data['overall_rating']){
                $(overall_rating).html(data['overall_rating']);
            }
            if(msg){
                $(msg).find('div.msg-default').hide();
                if(data['msg']) {
                    $(msg).find('div.msg-result').show();
                    $(msg).find('div.msg-result').html(data['msg']);
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                        $(msg).addClass('hidden');
                    }, 2000);
                } else {
                    $(msg).addClass('hidden');
                }
            }
            if(data['user_rating'] && data['user_rating']>0) {
                ui.select(parseInt(data['user_rating']));
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:** Okay, so I stripped it down to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form.rating').click({
    });
});
```

And it is still showing the same error. Could this have something to do with my jQuery script? The only other info it shows is this line, but I don't think it helps much, since the file has 3 lines in total: jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3

Comment: It doesn't say. It points to a line in the jquery min js, but that is useless as it is.

Comment: I'm still mastering jQuery, so maybe what you have is acceptable shorthand, but shouldn't it be: `$('form.rating').click(function() { //some code });`

Comment: I'm pretty new at jQuery too. You're right, if I do it that way I can send the ajax request no problem. But I can't access the callbacks that way:
`cancelShow:true, callback: function(ui, type, new_value) {`

Comment: did you try to remove all your script at all? remove link to jquery? get newer\other version of jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jquery click handler expects an anonymous function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form.rating').click(function() {
        // go for it!
    });
});
```

Comment: there is a way you can do .click({data:val}, function(){})... which works in isolation, but somehow, I've run into a problem with it. :-(

Answer (score 2):

@Ludder is close, but off by just a little.  He's right that you need to be passing a function as the argument to `click`, but it doesn't have to be anonymous.

```
a = {myFun: function(){console.log("a");}}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').click(a.myFun);
});
```

and

```
b = function(){console.log("b");}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').click(b);
});
```

and

```
function c () {console.log("c");}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').click(c);
});
```

All log their bit of the alphabet.  You were passing an empty object to click, give it a function instead.